# In search of a a random “sentence” or “line” generator based on predefined “sets” of words in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, generator

Not sure where I am supposed to ask this question, (if this is the wrong place, please help me locate the correct location).

I am in search of a a random "sentance" or "line" generator based on predefined "sets" of words. For example:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Set 1

Hey John,
Hi Mary,
How are you, Bob,
Set 2

Hope you are doing well.
Haven't seen you in awhile.
How's your son doing?
Set 3

My number changed. Here's my new one.
I'm late for something, gotta run
What's your number again? Can I call you later?
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Random Line from Set 1 + Random Line from Set 2 + Random Line from Set 3 = Random Mashup of All Sets

I.E. - Hi Mary, How's your Son Doing? My number changed. Here's my new one.

Does something like this exist in excel??

Answer (score 2):

With data in column **A**, use something like:

```
=INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(1,2)) & " " & INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(5,7)) & " " & INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(9,11))
```

[image]